# Wait for response from twitter website flask and tweepy

Tags: python, flask, tweepy

if I have something like this

```
auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerkey,consumer_secret)
redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
final_url='<a href='+redirect_url+'> Click here to verify</a>'

print redirect_url
return flask.render_template("index.html",url=final_url)
```

How could I then wait for the twitter website response before I run

```
auth.get_access_token(verifier) #That is, once we get 'verifier' from the user via an input
tweet=tweepy.API(auth)
tweet.update_status(text)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use Flask-OAuth for the oauth part of the twitter API?

Comment: I didn't know about flask oauth, I figured that I would take tweepy, then just implement it into a flask app, Could you explain how to do it with flask OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the Request context in flask ? It says "Functions marked with after_request() are called after a request and passed the response that will be sent to the client. They have to return that response object or a different one. They are however not guaranteed to be executed if an exception is raised, this is where functions marked with teardown_request() come in".